# Has to be my code in Falcon resources thread-safe?

Tags: falconframework

There are few thread-safety mentions in Falcon docs, but I'm still unsure whether or not my own code in resource responders (`on_get()`, `on_post()` etc.) have to be written in thread-safe manner.

I run Falcon with Gunicorn+nginx combo.

Answer (score 0):

If you employ threads to scale your application, then yes, your responders (e.g., `on_get()`), sinks, middleware methods, hooks and field converters need to be thread-safe, as they may be invoked in parallel. See also: [Is Falcon thread-safe?](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/faq.html#is-falcon-thread-safe)

If your responders are I/O bound, and you scale your application using Gevent or Asyncio (in the case of the [ASGI flavour of the framework](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/app.html#asgi-app)), this is usually less of a concern, but you still need to be aware of the possibility of your responders running "in parallel" in accordance to the chosen concurrency model.